# Regex to match string not ending with pattern

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I try to find a regex that matches the string only if the string does not end with at least three '0' or more. Intuitively, I tried:

```
.*[^0]{3,}$
```

But this does not match when there one or two zeroes at the end of the string.

Answer (score 15):

If you have to do it without lookbehind assertions (i. e. in JavaScript):

```
^(?:.{0,2}|.*(?!000).{3})$
```

Otherwise, use hsz's answer.

**Explanation:**

```
^          # Start of string
(?:        # Either match...
 .{0,2}    #  a string of up to two characters
|          # or
 .*        #  any string
 (?!000)   #   (unless followed by three zeroes)
 .{3}      #  followed by three characters
)          # End of alternation
$          # End of string
```

Answer (score 14):

You can try using a negative look-behind, i.e.:

```
(?<!000)$
```

Tests:

```
Test  Target String   Matches
1     654153640       Yes
2     5646549800      Yes   
3     848461158000    No
4     84681840000     No
5     35450008748     Yes
```

Please keep in mind that negative look-behinds aren't supported in every language, however.

Comment: This won't work in every implementation. It won't work in Javascript, for example. What were you doing it in?

Comment: Sure thing, that it needs tests. However this solution works well and be adapted with language not specified by op.

Comment: Which implementation did you try it in? Looking at the OP's profile he/she seems to be using bash a lot, which doesn't support lookbehinds, so this won't work and can't be adapted.

Comment: If you mention that this is a (negated) lookbehind, that would make it easier for readers to avoid a wild goose chase, by looking up whether their regex environment supports such things.

Comment: This worked in Visual Studio 2015 Find in Files: "do_(_\w+|[\w-[0-9_]]\w*(?<!Desc|Msg))\b" finds all C++ identifiers that do not end with Desc or Msg.

Answer (score 3):

What wrong with the no-look-behind, more general-purpose `^(.(?!.*0{3,}$))*$`?

The general pattern is `^(.(?!.*` + *`not-ending-with-pattern`* + `$))*$`. You don't have to reverse engineer the state machine like Tim's answer does; you just insert the pattern you don't want to match at the end.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those things that RegExes aren't that great at, because the string isn't very *regular* (whatever that means). The only way I could come up with was to give it every possibility.

```
.*[^0]..$|.*.[^0].$|.*..[^0]$
```

which simplifies to

```
.*([^0]|[^0].|[^0]..)$
```

That's fine if you only want strings not ending in three 0s, but strings not ending in ten 0s would be long. But thankfully, this string is a bit more *regular* than some of these sorts of combinations, and you can simplify it further.

```
.*[^0].{0,2}$
```