# Regex to match \W inside word, not ending with \W

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

How to regex match words that have digits or any non-characters inside words, excluding when digits and non-characters (`\/°†@*()'\s+&;±|-\^`) are at the end of word? I need to match `dAS2a` but not `dASI6`. Could not adapt the [Regex to match string not ending with pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431295/regex-to-match-string-not-ending-with-pattern) solution.

`dA/Sa
dAS2a
dASI/
dASI6`

http://regex101.com/r/qM4dV7/1 failed.

Comment: Does it have to *start* with a specific character? Are you testing each "word" one at a time or trying to find valid words in a long string? What is a "non-character" (assuming you mean non-letter)?

Comment: It should _ignore_ numbers or special characters at the end. In middle or beginning - does not matters. I'm trying to find valid words in a long string. "non-character" = non-letter.

Comment: Final question: if you are looking in a long string and a valid word can have non-alphanumeric characters (AKA: anything), what makes the start/end of a word? In other words, what delimits two words? Is it a space?

Comment: Each word in a new line, so \n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work just fine (if you use the `gmi` modifiers):

```regex
^.*[a-z]$
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/cG9tF1/2)

---

You said each word is on a new line. Using the `m` modifier we can anchor each expression to the beginning/end of a line with `^` and `$` anchors (without the modifier, this means beginning/end of the *string*). Then you said a word can essentially be anything (`.*`) as long as it ends in a non-digit or non-special character (I took that to mean a "letter", `[a-z]` with the `i` modifier).

Comment: I give you my thanks. Can it find only `dAS2a` and not `dA/Sa`?

Comment: You can replace `.*` with a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) of what characters you want to allow. For example, `^[a-z0-9]*[a-z]$` will only match alphanumeric "words" ending in letters.

Comment: I need to find and weed out "wrong" words, but `^[a-z0-9]*[a-z]$` accepts `dAS2a` as a good word, which it is not, it should locate it or ignore, better locate.